# Performance - UICollectionView Loading time very slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, performance, uicollectionview

I am writing an app that takes a picture using the iDevice camera and stores it on the file system as a PNG. When starting my app, I load a UICollectionView with the images found on the file system.

The issue I am facing is that the load time for the app (even when its only loading 6 images is approximately 4 seconds which is unacceptable.  I have implemented GCD to load images on a background thread (which keeps the UI snappy) however I really want the app to start far quicker with images loaded.

My thoughts are:

I suspect the `initWithContentsOfFile` is taking ages to load the full size image.
I thought about generating a separate thumbnail image when a picture is taken and load that instead.

Ultimately when I look at Apple's Photo app, it loads "instantly" and has 10's of pictures in view.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can load the images faster or at least appear to?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using `imageNamed` method?

Comment: would this necessarily load any faster?

Comment: Probably not in the first load, but `imageNamed` performs caching while the latter doesn't.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. I do having separate caching code, its the initial load that's the main problem.

Comment: Have you tried it in the device? And how big are the images? If they are pretty big in size, there is not much you can do other than load them asynchronously.

Comment: Yes I am running on the device and yes the images are normal image size (they are coming from the device's camera).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Load image in background thread and set in main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:frontPath];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.frontButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    });
});
```

Comment: I do this in the - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method but the initial load of the view takes ages.

Comment: its still taking time ??

Comment: Yes it is - because its the initial load that takes the time, not any reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample code and try to get some idea from it
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/lazytableimages/introduction/intro.html

Comment: Read that this morning and I don't see which bit helps?  Am I missing something? I understand I can put a placeholder image whilst the cells load, however that isn't what the Photo app does.

Comment: @Spanners: see this project helps to download images from network and in your case images data is stored on your local db, so try to take idea from this.. Hope this helps you, otherwise refer to some lazy image loading tutorials on web might helps you.